# How to find maximum value in parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

Here is an example of problem: a constant variable's template should expand its type based on parameters.  While direct way is possible, by giving size of type, or underlying typename, it's error-prone.

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t bit>
constexpr const uint16_t BIT = 1 << bit;

template<size_t... bits>
constexpr const uint16_t BITS = (uint16_t(1 << bits)|...);

int main()
{
    std::cout << BITS<0,1,3,12> << std::endl;
}
```

Idea is to implement template data type which would return `type` which is unsigned integer at least of size of greatest value in parameter pack. This also would allow to check if template arguments are sane.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty straight forward in C++17. The maximum value we can calculate with a simple invocation of `std::max` ([the initializer list overload is `constexpr` since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)).

The result we'll need to plug into a utility that maps sizes to integer types, but that's fairly simple to write now:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct size2Type {
    static auto type_calculator() {
        static_assert( N < 64 );
        if constexpr ( N < 8 )
            return uint8_t{};
        else if constexpr ( N < 16 )
            return uint16_t{};
        else if constexpr ( N < 32 )
            return uint32_t{};
        else
            return uint64_t{};
    }

    using type = decltype(type_calculator());
};
```

Then, putting it to use in your original example:

```
template<size_t bit>
constexpr typename size2Type<bit>::type BIT = (typename size2Type<bit>::type)(1) << bit;

template<size_t... bits>
constexpr typename size2Type<std::max({std::size_t(0), bits...})>::type BITS = (BIT<bits> | ... | 0);
```

I didn't prettify the cast, but a utility can be written to accomplish that too.

You can [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae87b4cddfca625d).

Comment: By "prettify" you mean get rid of the `typename blah::type` spam?  I mean, this isn't C++03.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Yes

Comment: This can be even simpler, because  there is library type from `boost` that can do the choice you did with `type_calculator`. But I apparently run into portability of  the max() trick. I have to look into implementation that works.

Comment: Consider allowing *no* bits. And using `BIT` in `BITS` would simplify things.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<std::size_t bits>
class uint_that_has_bits_helper {
  static auto calculator() {
    // conditionally compile lines based on compiler capabilities:
    if constexpr (bits <= 8) return std::uint8_t{};
    else if constexpr (bits <= 16) return std::uint16_t{};
    else if constexpr (bits <= 32) return std::uint32_t{};
    else if constexpr (bits <= 64) return std::uint64_t{};
    else if constexpr (bits <= 128) return std::uint128_t{};
  }
public:
  using type = declype(calculator());
};
template<std::size_t bits>
using uint_that_has_bits = typename uint_that_has_bits<bits>::type;

template<std::size_t index>
constexpr auto bit = uint_that_has_bits<index+1>(1) << uint_that_has_bits<index+1>(index);
```

now we can get:

```
template<std::size_t... index>
constexpr const auto bits = static_cast<uint_that_has_bits< std::max({index...})+1>>(bit<index> | ...);
```