# Mapping from a size to the corresponding uintN_t type

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, uint8t

Given a constexpr size `N`, is there some way to map it at compile-time to the corresponding `uintN_t` type, without writing my own exhaustive mapping, such as:

```
template <size_t N>
struct size_to_type {};

template<>
struct size_to_type<8> { using type = uint8_t; };

template<>
struct size_to_type<16> { using type = uint16_t; };

// etc
```

I'm fine with an error when the corresponding type doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think so, except maybe with a macro.

Comment: Whatever method you choose, it will at least (macros aside) require explicitly mentioning all the types (though it can be done shorter). But there are only four possibilities anyway, so I am not sure that that is such a burden.

Comment: Even with macros I'm going to end up with at best `MACRO(8) MACRO(16) MACRO(32) ...` right?

Comment: You pretty much just wrote it yourself. C++ doesn't really have a reputation for being compact. This is exactly how you do this.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Yes, I think macros would be limited to that kind of use.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but there are ways to make it compact in C++17. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57645001/817643 - still, one can't avoid spelling it out some way

Answer (score 5):

> is there some way to map it at compile-time to the corresponding uintN_t type, without writing my own exhaustive mapping [?]

The best I can imagine is a type traits that, given a number (size) and a list of types (a sequence of `std::uintXX_t` or what do you prefer), select the first type that contain exactly the givens number of bytes.

Require some works but is reusable for different list of types.

Given the following recursive helper class

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename,
          bool = (N == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T0))>
struct st_helper;

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename Tpl>
struct st_helper<N, T0, Tpl, true>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<T1, Ts...>, false>
   : public st_helper<N, T1, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0>
struct st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<>, false>
 { };
```

the custom type is

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct selectType : public st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts>
using selectType_t = typename selectType<N, Ts...>::type;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename,
          bool = (N == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T0))>
struct st_helper;

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename Tpl>
struct st_helper<N, T0, Tpl, true>
 { using type = T0; };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<T1, Ts...>, false>
   : public st_helper<N, T1, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0>
struct st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<>, false>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct selectType : public st_helper<N, T0, std::tuple<Ts...>>
 { };

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts>
using selectType_t = typename selectType<N, Ts...>::type;

int main ()
 {
   using t08 = selectType_t<8u,  std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
                                 std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;
   using t16 = selectType_t<16u, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
                                 std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;
   using t32 = selectType_t<32u, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
                                 std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;
   using t64 = selectType_t<64u, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
                                 std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;

   // compilation error
   //using t24 = selectType_t<24u, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
   //                              std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<t08, std::uint8_t> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<t16, std::uint16_t> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<t32, std::uint32_t> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<t64, std::uint64_t> );
 }
```

If you prefer, you can modify `st_helper` to select the first type that contain `N` bytes, changing the `==` in `<=`

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T0, typename,
          bool = (N <= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T0))>
struct st_helper;// ^^
```

This way, `t24` now compile

```
   // now compile
   using t24 = selectType_t<24u, std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t,
                                 std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t>;
```

and become `std::uint32_t`